# Fail: Code: 404 Value: Not Found details (if any): Resource not found for the segment 'Jobs' Microsoft Azure [Blob Creation] PHP SDK

Tags: php, azure, drupal, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Media Services for audio & video file processing. I'm getting an error message like, Resource not found for the segment Jobs while I'm doing the video & audio file processing

> [message:protected] => Fail:
> Code: 404
> Value: Not Found
> details (if any): Resource not found for the segment 'Jobs'..

- Status Code: 404
- Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'Jobs'..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Azure Media Services for audio & video file processing. Initially, I got a response like "Resources not found for the segment Jobs".

The literal meaning for the error message is like, the resources not found for the segment Jobs. The initial suspect for the issue with that error message, maybe I misconfigured some information in the blob, for that reason, it's not allowing us to process data. Later on, I found that the information which I'm passing to Azure Media Services has already processed JobId & all the details.

> [message:protected] => Fail:
> Code: 404
> Value: Not Found
> details (if any): Resource not found for the segment 'Jobs'..

- Status Code: 404
- Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'Jobs'..

[My Scenario for that issue: I have stored processed jobId & file path and other information in the database, mistakenly I'm taking the processed file details & passing it, again and again, got the same error]